# viewClass property in UrlBasedViewResolver

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

While creating application using Spring Framework if we want to use UrlBasedViewResolver we need to specify property viewClass, I could not find any good docs which explains why this property is required and what can be achieved using this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property specifies what Class will be used to render a view.  By Default it is AbstractUrlBasedView.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/UrlBasedViewResolver.html